# Excel add page breaks dynamically so that they do not split titles from paragraphs

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing

I am currently working on a document in Excel that needs to be printed fairly regularly. However, whenever a user tries to print the doc, it will insert page breaks in such a way that it breaks the look of the document. What I mean by that specifically is that it will often separate the section title from the text that should go with it, so I'm left with a title at the very end of a page, and an unnamed paragraph started the next page. Is there a way around this? I have tried adding a column and merging cells so that page breaks would only be allowed after the cell, but Excel does not respect that

Comment: Section titles? Paragraphs? Are you sure you should not be using Word? Excel is not a layout application.

Comment: It uses formulas and fancy VBA, so it can't really be done in word, unfortunately

Comment: Can't even link the Excel file to a Word doc?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, didn't even know that was a thing

Comment: See [this](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/insert-excel-spreadsheet-in-word-document)